# Route camel cron expression

Tags: java, kotlin, cron, apache-camel

I would like to include a scheduler in my camel route that will start it every day at 8.
This is my route that takes a file from an ftp:

```
from(
            "$uri?" +
                    "password=RAW($pass)" +
                    "&include=$source_file_type" +
                    "&passiveMode=true" +
                    "&delete=true"
        )
            .log("Connected to FTP")
```

I tried to put in my from this:

```
"&scheduler.cron=$cron_expression"
```

but it did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/ftp-component.html) for `scheduler` property of FTP Component.

> To use a cron scheduler from either camel-spring or camel-quartz component. The value can be one of: none, spring, quartz

To use a cron style expression, you need to couple FTP with one of the two scheduler options mentioned in the docs.

For using quartz as a scheduler in Camel 3.x, try this

1. Add dependency to camel-quartz
2. Add params `scheduler=quartz&scheduler.cron=<your crown expression>` to FTP route definition

If you are using Camel 2.x,

1. Add dependency to camel-quartz2
2. Add params `scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=<your crown expression>` to FTP route definition